# Cannot filter rows on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have SQL script

Here is code

```
  UPDATE Companies
    LEFT JOIN abpusers a on a.CompanyId = companies.Id AND a.TenantId IS NOT NULL
SET Companies.TenantId = a.TenantId
WHERE Companies.TenantId = 3;
```

The problem in that I try to run it and get an error

> [23000][1048] Column 'TenantId' cannot be null

But I have condition `AND a.TenantId IS NOT NULL` that must filter it

Where is my problem?

Comment: You need an `INNER JOIN`, or to move your filter to the where clause, not on the join condition. Since you have put `a.TenantId IS NOT NULL` on the join clause, you are removing these rows from the left hand side of the join, and not filtering these rows out of the update completely

Answer (score 0):

Since you used LEFT JOIN some of the companies rows won’t have matching abpusers, which will result in NULL.

Instead of updating you can see it by doing a SELECT on the same join and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Companies

```
LEFT JOIN abpusers a on a.CompanyId = companies.Id AND NULLIF(a.TenantId ,' ')  IS NOT NULL
```

SET Companies.TenantId = a.TenantId

WHERE Companies.TenantId = 3